# MATLAB: Defining n subsets of a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, matrix

I have a 1974x1 vector, `Upper`, and I am trying to break the information up into individual arrays of 36 items each. So, I used length to find that there are 1974 items and then divided by 36 and used the `floor` function. I cannot figure out how to do it all with `n`.

Here is my logic: I am defining `n` in an attempt to find the number of subsets that need to be defined. Then, I am trying to have subsetn become subset1, subset2,...,subset36. However, MATLAB only definies the matrix subsetn as a 1x36 matrix. However, this matrix contains what subset1 is supposed to contain(1...36). Do you guys have any advice for a newbie? What am I doing wrong?

```
binSize = 36;
nData = length(Upper);
nBins = floor(nData/36);
nDiscarded = nData  - binSize*nBins;

n=1:binSize;
subsetn= [(n-1)*binSize+1:n*binSize];
```

Comment: Can you simplify your example a bit and give some concrete expected results:  suppose `Upper` is `5x1` (in fact, suppose it is equal to `[10; 11; 12; 13; 14]`) and `binSize` is 2.  what values should  `subset1`, `subset2` and `subset3` have?  what should be the values of `subsetn`?

Comment: Thank you for the response! here is an example: if Upper was 5x1 and binSize is 2, there would be 2 subsets. subset1 would be [1 2] and subset2 would be [3 4]. In your example, 5 would be discarded. Subsetn shouldn't exist, I wrote it because I wanted to simplify the process of creating subset1 and subset2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a 54x36 array where the `n`th column is your `n`th subset.

```
subsetArray=reshape(x(1:binSize*nBins),[],nBins);
```

You can access the `n`th subset as `subsetArray(:,n)`

Comment: change that `36` to `binSize`?

Comment: THank you, that's a great idea. One problem I am having is that there are 54 items in each column instead of 36 as there should be. How should I adjust it so that there are 36 sequential entries in each column and so that subsetArray is a 36x54 matrix? sorry, I'm really new to this!

Comment: @Alex: Please check now. The 36 in the line should've been 54, which has been replaced by `nBins` to make it general.

Comment: Thank you so much yoda, I was really stuck! To me, very good advice you give :P

Answer (score 1):

Sorry in advance if I misunderstood what you want to do.

I think the following little trick might do what you want (it's hacky, but I'm no Matlab expert):

```
[a, b] = meshgrid(0:nBins-1, 0:binSize-1)
inds = a*binSize + b + 1
```

Now `inds` is a nBins*binSize matrix of indices. You can index Upper with it like

```
Upper(inds)
```

which should give you the subsets as the columns in the resulting matrix.

Edit: on seeing Yoda's answer, his is better ;)